# Histogram along one dimension in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram

Assume I have an `N×M` matrix `A`. I would like to compute the histogram for each column of `A`. The naïve way would be to do something like this:

```
edges = 0:5:100;
counts = zeros(numel(edges) - 1, M);
for i_c = 1:M
  counts(:, i_c) = histcounts(A(:, i_c), edges);
end
```

Is there a better (faster) way to do this?

**Edit: Add some performance tests**

OK, let's do some testing. First `histcounts` + loop, then an alternative using `arrayfun` and an indexing vector, then [btmcnellis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934087/1893154)/[randomGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934055/1893154)'s solution with `cellfun`, finally [obchardon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934266/1893154)'s solution using `histc`.
It seems like for long columns, `histcount` is more efficient. But for shorter but many columns, `histc` wins by a great margin!

```
niter = 10;

M = 100;
N = 10000;

A = rand(M, N);
edges = 0:.05:1;


counts1 = zeros(numel(edges) - 1, N);
counts2 = zeros(numel(edges) - 1, N);
counts3 = zeros(numel(edges) - 1, N);
counts4 = zeros(numel(edges), N);

tic;
for i_r = 1:niter
    for i_c = 1:N
        counts1(:, i_c) = histcounts(A(:, i_c), edges);
    end
end
toc

tic;
for i_r = 1:niter
    counts2 = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(ind) histcounts(A(:, ind), edges), 1:size(A, 2), 'UniformOutput', 0)')';
end
toc

tic;
for i_r = 1:niter
    Acell = num2cell(A, 1);
    counts3 = cell2mat(cellfun(@(column) histcounts(column, edges), Acell, 'UniformOutput', 0)')';
end
toc

tic;
for i_r = 1:niter
    counts4 = histc(A, edges, 1);
end
toc

all(counts1(:) == counts2(:))
all(counts1(:) == counts3(:))
counts4 = counts4(1:numel(edges)-1, :); % histc has an extra bin
all(counts1(:) == counts4(:))
```

Actual tests:

```
niter = 100; 
M = 10000;
N = 100;
```

> Elapsed time is 2.423785 seconds.
>   Elapsed time is 2.730303 seconds.
>   Elapsed time is 3.774217 seconds.
>   Elapsed time is 2.721766 seconds.

```
niter = 10;
M = 100;
N = 10000;
```

> Elapsed time is 5.438335 seconds.
>   Elapsed time is 7.387587 seconds.
>   Elapsed time is 7.647818 seconds.
>   Elapsed time is 0.276491 seconds.

Comment: Would `edges` be `0:5:100` in your actual case too?

Comment: @Divakar I would not want to exclude other values, but what would your suggestion fro that special case be?

Comment: Well, I was trying to threshold at progressive stepsize of `5` and then use accumarray in a loop along the columns, but seems like that's pretty slow. So, I guess, go with the `histc` or `histcounts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `histc`

```
x = [0:5:100];
y = histc(A,x, dim);
```

where `dim` is the dimension along which to count.

And then

```
hist(y(:,1),x);
hist(y(:,2),x);
...
```

Comment: I had totally forgotten that use of `histc` ... On the [discouraged instances of histc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/replace-discouraged-instances-of-hist-and-histc.html) they actually suggest to replace `histc` in my use case with the loop..

Comment: @zeeMonkeez: But keep in mind that the code is more compact but (i suppose) slower. Histcount is probably more efficient.

Comment: My brief testing shows that actually, `histc` and looped `histcounts` takes exactly the same time ... I'll update the question with test results.

Comment: I tested (over a 100x100000 matrix) and I obtained 1.6 seconds with `histc` and 0.4 seconds with your `histcounts` loop. So we should probably trust the mathwork's guys.

Answer (score 0):

Split the array A into a cell array where each cell is a single column from the matrix:

```
Acell = [mat2cell(A',ones(1,M))]';
```

Apply the function using `cellfun` to each cell of the cell array `Acell`

```
counts = cellfun(@(x)histcounts(x,edges),Acell);
```

counts will be a cell array with each cell containing histcounts from the respective column of A.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) and [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), although I don't know how this compares with the naive method performance-wise.

`num2cell` by default takes a matrix and converts it into a cell array where each cell contains one element of the matrix, but passing a second argument allows you to do so along a particular dimension. So for 2x3 matrix `A`, `num2cell(A, 1)` will return a 1x3 cell array where each cell contains a 2-by-1 column of A.

`cellfun` applies a function to each element of a cell. So in this case you could take a cell array `C` output from `num2cell` as above and apply histcounts to each column of `A` as follows:

```
counts = cellfun(@(column) histcounts(column, edges), C);
```

`counts` should then be a 3-element array, where the i-th element contains the `histcounts` result for the i-th column of `A`.

(Note that the `@()` syntax above is an [anonymous function.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html))